Postgres query table with max value in row with group by
Suppose I have the following data, and I want to know for each person what was their highest performing period, breaking ties in favor of more recent periods.
I would like to see ONLY the following rows:
5 (Alice's best row)
8 (Bob's best row)
9 (Charlie's best row)
11 (Danny's best, and only, row)
The stuff I have seen with window functions will bring back way more rows than I want.
Starting with something like
select employee_id, employee_name, quarter, year, 
max(sales_amount) over (partition by employee_id) 
from employeeperformance

This brings back all of the rows with the correct sales amount, but there is no practical way (yes could do join on the employee ID and the sales amount back to the original table and then order them by date and then cut out any tied rows, but there has to be a better way) to get back which period that is associated with, let alone with was the most recent period with that value.
Is there any way to get the 4 rows I am looking for?
INSERT INTO employeeperformance VALUES
(101,'Alice','Q2',2023,20000),
(101,'Alice','Q3',2023,20000),
(101,'Alice','Q4',2023,20000),
(101,'Alice','Q1',2024,20000),
(101,'Alice','Q2',2024,25000),
(102,'Bob','Q4',2023,15000),
(102,'Bob','Q1',2024,15000),
(102,'Bob','Q2',2024,30000),
(103,'Charlie','Q1',2024,28000),
(103,'Charlie','Q2',2024,22000),
(104,'Danny','Q2',2024,22000)



DISTINCT ON makes this simple and fast:
SELECT DISTINCT ON (employee_id)
       employee_id, employee_name, quarter, year, sales_amount
FROM   employeeperformance
ORDER  BY employee_id, sales_amount DESC, year DESC, quarter DESC;

See:

Select first row in each GROUP BY group?

Aside: Your table seems in need of normalization.

Using a window function you can generate a row_number of a partition defined by the employee_id and ranked/ordered using the logic you describe. Then just filter the results:
SELECT *
FROM 
   (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY employee_id ORDER BY sales_amount DESC, year DESC, quarter DESC) as rn
    FROM yourtable
   ) dt
WHERE rn=1


sales_amount DESC, year DESC, quarter DESC
